# mongoose $aggregate $lookup does not returns data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have below code

```
Users.aggregate([{
            $match: dt //working fine
        }, {
            $lookup: { //not working returns []
                from: "points",
                localField: "_id", //field in user collection
                foreignField: "user", //field in points collection
                as: "points"
            }
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "orders", //not working returns []
                localField: "_id", //field in user collection
                foreignField: "user_id", //field in orders collection
                as: "orders"
            }
        }], (err, data) => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: "success",
                data: data ? data : [],
                status: true
            })
        })
```

there are 16 records in points and orders collections but it always returns empty array. 
I am unable to find the issue. Please help. 
in points and orders collections user id is added.
Is there any other way to find data in these collections with user table? I didn't find anything except populate to do so.

> MongoDB server version: 3.6.9
>
> "mongoose": "^5.3.4"

Comment: What is your version of your driver Mongodb and/or the mongoose library?  Are the collections in the same database?  Would you have an item example for each schema?  To help debug make sure your mongoose.set('debug', true).  You can also look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-explain to help debug.

Comment: @Plpicard thenks for comment. my MongoDB server version: 3.6.9 and "mongoose": "^5.3.4". and collections are in the same database.

Comment: Problem solved. the Issue was in points collection field type of user was `String`. I have changed type to `Schema.Types.ObjectId` and its working fine with new records.